# Google Sites HTML export keeps redirecting to live site

Tags: html, google-sites, google-sites-2016

I was trying to export a Google Site I made for a project. I used *wget* to spider through every page and to download the html files and linked content. When I try to open "index.html" in Chrome, it does open the local HTML file, but it redirects me to the live version immediately after.

Is there anyway I could modify the HTML code so that it won't head straight to the actual website? I just want to have a local copy of it for reference, and I don't want to store it on Drive.

As the HTML file is too big to type out, I have provided it on Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/bEBEUmUi).

```
.
```

Comment: Can you share us your index.html file here (please edit the question with code)

Comment: I just updated my post; let me know if you can help.

Comment: I went through your index.html page. There are many ways to redirect (automatically) to another site. As it is a big file, it's hard to find out. I could see meta tags with url which may be the one forwards your page. By the way what are you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: It’s just a Google Sites website I did for a school project; I want to archive it by having a local copy, as I won’t have access to my school account in the future.

Comment: in a short answer, it would not be so easy to do as you are trying to download directly. Better to find some other options (to deploy some application in the school machine) or something else like that. Downloading (like what you are trying) is not at all a good option.

Comment: `http://mobirise.net/offline-website-builder-software.html` this may help you !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need a better question. No website works offline, or they do if you download all the files to your user’s computer so the user can view it offline. But at some point they had to visit it online to get it.

Or you save it as an html site and hand it to them on a USB drive. That’s offline to that extent. But then it’s not really a website, its an html file.

Or otherwise, if you need a website for your school which can be used by anyone through internet / intranet, you have two options -

**1**. Create and host a website in an online server
.    **a**. You have to buy space and deploy a server yourself.
.   **b**. They will a run website in their webserver for you. You just need to give money

**2**. Deploy a webserver in the school's any one machine and get it in other machines.

Rephrase the question for a better answer.

Comment: With the reference to using `wget` it seems pretty clear that they *were* referring to having html files for offline browsing. (Pedantics aside about whether it's a website) The main problem about the page reloading to the online site is unusual in itself. It's worth a question of its own. I've just observed the same unusual behavior.